# Committng SQL transactions from PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, t-sql, transactions, commit

I am looking to run this code here:

```
Write-Host "Running script"

$SQLServer4 = "ServerA" 
$Database4 = 'master'


Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer4 -Database $Database4 -InputFile "C:\Users\Documents\Scripts\SaveSite.txt"
```

There is a commit statement in the script, it is commented out and you have to run it manually as long as the output looks good. This is fine and all when I do it in SSMS, but I am not sure how to run the commit statement from PowerShell.

I tried running the following:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "commit" -ServerInstance "ServerA"
```

and I am getting this error:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION. 
Msg 3902, Level 16, State 1, Procedure , Line 1.
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: If the script has a commented-out `COMMIT` at the end, then the transaction will be rolled back when the connection is terminated. The latter connection you make is a completely different scope, so can't commit a transaction that doesn't exist.

Comment: This is quite simply not possible with `Invoke-Sqlcmd`. The whole thing is transmitted as a series of statements over a single connection. The script itself *must* contain the `COMMIT`. What you can do is include something like `IF $(DoCommit) = 1 COMMIT`, and pass `-Variable 'DoCommit=1'`. This means you must also execute the script in sqlcmd mode in other contexts, though. Alternatively, some good-old fashioned string concatenation in PowerShell itself can do it, if the `COMMIT` is the last statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can just concat  `COMMIT` to the script

```
Write-Host "Running script"

$SQLServer4 = "ServerA" 
$Database4 = 'master'

$script = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Documents\Scripts\SaveSite.txt" -Raw;

$script += "
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    COMMIT;
";

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer4 -Database $Database4 -Query $script;
```

Comment: I am getting this error 'Invoke-Sqlcmd : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Query'. Specified method is not supported.'

Comment: Needs `-Raw` to get the file as a single string

Comment: Ok. I did that and nothing errored out. The output is the same as if I would have just run it without the enhancements you made. How do I know the script committed?

Comment: Check the database, @movement ; see if the changes the script is meant to do appear in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using sqlcmd, you can use sqlcmd variables in your file. Here's a quick test I wired up:

```sql
if ('$(COMMIT)' = '1')
   print 'committing';
else
   print 'not committing';
```

Then, when you go to call it, you can optionally pass in a value for the commit variable

```
C:\temp
> sqlcmd -S . -E -i .\sqlcmd-test.sql -v COMMIT=1
committing
C:\temp
> sqlcmd -S . -E -i .\sqlcmd-test.sql
'COMMIT' scripting variable not defined.
not committing
C:\temp
>
```

I would view it as a feature and not a bug that the case in which you're not passing in a variable warns you about the COMMIT variable not being defined. This is a signal to you that if you want to commit the results you've got to do something.

Answer (score -1):

The transaction is committed implicitly when the session ends.

If you need to hold a transaction open, **you will not be able to use `Invoke-SqlCommand`** Instead, you'll probably need to manually create and use ADO.Net objects like `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, and `SqlTransaction`.

This is a **bad idea**, btw. SQL Server will hold resources like locks until a transaction completes, making this a good way to create deadlocks on your server. Transactions are *not intended for confirming long-running operations*. Instead, they are intended for safe-guarding against errors/incompletions in complex operations that should still finish within a reasonable time. If you have complex operations with lower up-front confidence needing review, they should be pushed to a staging area in one (brief) transaction, then on confirmation pushed live in another (brief) transaction.

Comment: So I really don't need to do anything then if the transaction is committed implicitly when the session ends?

Comment: *"The transaction is committed implicitly when the session ends."* This isn't [default behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaUAm.png)

Comment: @ThomA Don't think this is *any* behaviour never mind the default. A hanging transaction is always rolled back when the connection is closed (which might be after some time). Implicit transactions is related to starting not ending a transaction.

Comment: I agree that I didn't think it was *any* behaviour, but I didn't want to outright refute Joel, @Charlieface ; perhaps they had omitted something of import.